# Keyerror:None ,I don't understand this problem

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

```
class KITTIRAWDataset(KITTIDataset):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(KITTIRAWDataset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def get_image_path(self, folder, frame_index, side):
    self.img_ext='.png'
    f_str = "{:010d}{}".format(frame_index, self.img_ext)
    image_path = os.path.join(
        self.data_path, folder, "image_0{}/data".format(self.side_map[side]), f_str)
    return image_path

def get_depth(self, folder, frame_index, side, do_flip):
    calib_path = os.path.join(self.data_path, folder.split("/")[0])
    # calib_path: D:/SomeExperiments/KITTRawData/2011_09_26
    velo_filename = os.path.join(
        self.data_path,
        folder,
        # Only change is using colon (:) instead of %. For example, instead of %s use {:s} and instead of %d use (:d}
        # 010d: the integer length 10
        "velodyne_points/data/{:010d}.bin".format(int(frame_index)))
    depth_gt = generate_depth_map(calib_path, velo_filename, self.side_map[side])
    depth_gt = skimage.transform.resize(
        depth_gt, self.full_res_shape[::-1], order=0, preserve_range=True, mode='constant')

    if do_flip:
        depth_gt = np.fliplr(depth_gt)
    # print(type(depth_gt)) 'numpy.ndarray'
    return
```

when I was running my code, an error occured, like below:
[image]

I have changed my torch version which refers to the author's markdown, but it can't solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

`KeyError` means that you are trying to get a value from a dict with a key that does not exist. In the line displayed you have `self.side_map[side])` and `KeyError: None` means that the key is *None*, so your *side* variable have a value *None*.

That is what we an know looking at the code, the error and without more context